# Python - MySQLdb parametrized query

Tags: python, mysql-python, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a simple script for changing some mysql data, but I'm little bit confused about parametrized queries. The code look like this:

```
reader_id = sys.argv[1]
cmd_id = sys.argv[2]

conn = mysql.connect(user='...', passwd='...', host='...', db='...')
curs = conn.cursor()

mysql_data = {
    "reader_id": int(reader_id),
    "cmd_id": int(cmd_id)
}

curs.execute("UPDATE `reader_config_hw` SET `changed_` = '1' "
             "WHERE `object_id` = %(reader_id)d AND `id` = %(cmd_id)d;", mysql_data)

curs.execute("UPDATE `reader` SET `check_for_command` = '1' WHERE `id` = %(reader_id)d", mysql_data)
```

and the error result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 25, in <module>
    "WHERE `object_id` = %(reader_id)d AND `id` = %(cmd_id)d;", mysql_data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 210, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

It says that number is required but I already changed the type of the variable by `int(reader_id)`, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing 
`"WHERE 'object_id' = %(reader_id)d AND 'id' = %(cmd_id)d;"`

to

`"WHERE 'object_id' = %(reader_id)s AND 'id' = %(cmd_id)s;"`

I think the 'd' after your variable calls indicates a "digit" whereas you need to use a string.

**EDIT**: to clarify, strings can be used in place of integers in MySQL queries

Comment: That works and I've already tried this solution. The problem is that when using `%(variable)s`, the IDE I'm using (pyChram) complains when parsing the SQL query. Also I would like to have some explanation why this is happening.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with pyCharm. Hope you get a solution soon! Sorry I couldn't be of more help :(